# Linear Programming- A shipment of three products in a cargo plane.

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, optimization, linear-programming, constraints

Suppose we want to maximize revenue in the following situation.

We have 3 shipments of products.

Shipment one:

```
               *Has 10 ton of loads available for shipment  

                *A revenue of 700 euro per ton.   

              *Occupies 2000 units of Volume per ton
```

Shipment two:

```
              *Has 12 ton of loads available for shipment
             
              *A revenue of 725 euro per ton. 
             
             *Occupies 3500 units of Volume per ton
```

Shipment three:

```
              *Has 17 ton of loads available for shipment
             
               *A revenue of 685 euro per ton. 
               
               *Occupies 3000 units of Volume per ton
```

The plane which will carry these shipments can hold in total **32 ton**

It is also split into 3 sections on the left and right:

**Right Side**

Hold A: Volume=16,000 units  Weight=18% of total ( which I calculated to be 5.76 ton)

Hold B: Volume=20,000 units  Weight=25% of total ( which I calculated to be 8 ton)

Hold C: Volume=14,000 units  Weight=7% of total ( which I calculated to be 2.24 ton)

**Left side**

Hold A: Volume=10,000 units  Weight=18% of total ( which I calculated to be 5.76 ton)

Hold B: Volume=20,000 units  Weight=25% of total ( which I calculated to be 8 ton)

Hold C: Volume=12,000 units  Weight=7% of total ( which I calculated to be 2.24 ton).

**The Objective funtion**

I believe would be

$$700x+725y+685z=R$$

Where $x=$ number of tons of shipment 1, $y=$number of tons of shipment 2, $z=$ number of tons of shipment 3

**Constraints**

I would have thought the constraints would be

1. $$0 \leq x \leq 10$$, $$0\leq y\leq 12$$, $$0\leq z\leq17$$ ( as there is a limited amount of each shipment in tons)
2. $$x+y+z\leq32$$ ( as the total amount of tons that can fit on the plane is 32)
3. $$2000x+3500y+3000z\leq92,000$$ (As each ton of shipment occupies a specific volume and there is a max Volume that the combination of all the holds on the right and left can hold.

Then I thought separate constraints would be needed for each of the individual containers.

Note: I edited in the subscripts after the advice of a comment. These variables are such that

$x_{1a}+x_{1b}+x_{1c}+x_{2a}+x_{2b}+x_{2c}=x$

$y_{1a}+y_{1b}+y_{1c}+y_{2a}+y_{2b}+y_{2c}=y$

$z_{1a}+z_{1b}+z_{1c}+z_{2a}+z_{2b}+z_{2c}=z$

**Right hold A**

$$x_{1a}+y_{1a}+z_{1a}\leq 5.76$$

$$2000x_{1a}+3500y_{1a}+3000z{1a}\leq 16,000$$

**Right hold B**

$$x_{1b}+y_{1b}+z_{1b}\leq 8$$

$$2000x_{1b}+3500y_{1b}+3000z_{1b}\leq 20,000$$

**Right hold C**

$$x_{1c}+y_{1c}+z_{1c}\leq 2.24$$

$$2000x_{1c}+3500y_{1c}+3000z_{1c}\leq 14,000$$

**Left hold A**

$$x_{2a}+y_{2a}+z_{2a}\leq 5.76$$

$$2000x_{2a}+3500y_{2a}+3000z_{2a}\leq 10,000$$

**Left hold B**

$$x_{2b}+y_{2b}+z_{2b}\leq 8$$

$$2000x_{2b}+3500y_{2b}+3000z_{2b}\leq 20,000$$

**Left hold C**

$$x_{2c}+y_{2c}+z_{2c}\leq 2.24$$

$$2000x_{2c}+3500y_{2c}+3000z_{2c}\leq 12,000$$

After this I thought that there would be a maximum for the revenue for each hold and I could use this to find the overall maximum. However when I put this into Wolfram calculator I found that it says there are no local Maxima. Could someone help me see where I'm going wrong and advise me on what I should do instead ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You wrote the inequalities for the individual holds as if the entire cargo were in each hold. That just reduces the volume restriction to the smallest hold (left hold A) and the weight restriction to the hold that can hold the least weight (right hold C). You need separate variables for the amounts of each product in each hold. However, the different problem you've formulated should still have a solution – you should link to your Wolfram|Alpha calculation so we can see what went wrong there.

Comment: @joriki https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=daa12bbf5e4daec7b363737d6d496120 This one gives the local max for the whole plane as (0,0,0) . https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=daa12bbf5e4daec7b363737d6d496120 this one says there is no max if I took away the constraint about the max amount of x,y,z, I have that may be that it would leave it unbounded and so a solution can't be found ?

Comment: @joriki Hi Joriki, I see what you mean. I think I've edited to correct my error now. Could you have a look at it and tell me if you think it seems ok like that now please ?

Comment: Seems right to me now. Your link above (it's the same one twice) doesn't work; it just leads to the widget page and doesn't contain your problem. You can link to your problem by clicking "Solve", clicking on the orange equals sign at the lower right and linking to the page you get there. The widget says "max: 9 variables", so it looks like you won't be able to use it for your problem.